# Laravel foreign key uuid

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have some problems with uuid foreign key with Laravel.
I have created tables like:

```
Schema::create('product_attributes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->string('label');
            $table->integer('default_order')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::create('product_attributes_value', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
            $table->string('value');
            $table->integer('default_order')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('attribute_id')->references('id')->on('product_attributes');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

And it's always giving

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table
> `ecommerce`.`product_attributes_value` (errno: 150 "Foreign key
> constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table
> `product_attributes_value` add constraint
> `product_attributes_value_attribute_id_foreign` foreign key
> (`attribute_id`) references `product_attributes` (`id`))

I can't see a problem, can you?

Comment: `$table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');` to `$table->uuid('attribute_id');`  both datatype should be same

Answer (score 1):

your are mapping an integer column to uuid column, type of **attribute_id** column in **product_attributes_value** table should be same as **id** column in **product_attributes** table

change:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id');
```

to:

```
$table->uuid('attribute_id')->nullable(false);
```

Comment: hello im having the same problem but i already try this solution but not working for me and it still show the same error which is "  Can't create table (Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed )"

Answer (score -1):

**change**

```
$table->foreign('attribute_id')
```

**to**

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('attribute_id')
```

Comment: `$table->uuid('id');` primary key with unsigned attr , on creating foriegn key both attr are same other wise return `error`

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing it - keep in mind that others should be able to learn from it